# Web.py on dotcloud with wsgi

Tags: python, wsgi, web.py

I'm trying to deploy my web.py app on dotcloud, but can't figure out how to do it.

I went through this tutorial fine:  http://docs.dotcloud.com/static/tutorials/firststeps/

And then I looked at http://docs.dotcloud.com/static/components/python/ ...

> The python service can host any python
>   web application compatible with the
>   WSGI standard.
>
> That includes all modern Python web
>   frameworks: Django, Pylons, web.py,
>   web2py, etc.
>
> ...
>
> python runs with Nginx + uWSGI,
>   managed by supervisord. Static assets
>   are served directly by Nginx, for
>   greater performance.
>
> ...
>
> DotCloud relies on well-established tools and conventions to build your app. 
>   It should be trivial to adapt any application to run on DotCloud.
>
> ...
>
> When deploying your app, DotCloud
>   looks for a file called wsgi.py. Make
>   sure to create that file at the root
>   of your application directory.

---

Googling "web.py wsgi" leads to http://webpy.org/install which has a pretty bewildering array of instructions.  I tried a number of suggestions on the page, but couldn't get anything to work.

The most promising prospect seemed to be creating a file called wsgi.py like so:

```
import web

urls = (
  '/(.*)', 'hello'
)

class hello:    
  def GET(self, name):
    if not name: 
      name = 'World'
    return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=False)
application = app.wsgifunc()
```

I also created an empty `__init__.py` next to it.

Then I did:

```
dotcloud create jca_hello.py
dotcloud deploy -t python jca_hello.www
dotcloud push jca_hello.www .
```

But now when I go to http://www.jca_hello.dotcloud.com/ all I see is:

> uWSGI Error
>
> wsgi application not found

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am fellow user of web.py and I work at DotCloud by the way :-)

We use uWSGI to run your WSGI application. The point is that uWSGI is looking for a variable named "application".

Here is what I usually do:

```
app = web.application(urls, globals())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
else:
    web.config.debug = False
    application = app.wsgifunc()
```

So you can both continue to use your app on your local machine:

```
$ python ./wsgi.py
```

And push it on production (on DotCloud of course ;) with debug mode disabled.

Here is your wsgi.py file corrected:

```
import web

urls = (
  '/(.*)', 'Hello'
)

class Hello(object):

    def GET(self, name):
        if not name:
            name = 'World'
        return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

app = web.application(urls, globals())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
else:
    web.config.debug = False
    application = app.wsgifunc()
```

Beware of correctly having your wsgi.py in your approot.

Also make sure that you have a file named "requirements.txt" in your approot containing:

```
web.py
```

In the meantime, do not hesitate to contact the DotCloud support if you have any problem with your deployments.

Comment: Awesome.  It works.  I must say I did not expect to get a detailed answer from a dotcloud dev within 2 hours :)

Comment: the 'application' variable in the original question exists already. no?